# Airflow - Cannot connect to external postgres server

Tags: postgresql, docker, airflow

I have a working instance of Airflow running using standard Docker params.

I am attempting to contact a separate postgresql server (as in, not the one airflow uses), on the same network, and not using docker.

The postgresl server is running on:

- host: 192.168.4.4
- port: 30991
- user: readuser

I have added a connection under airflow -> admin -> connections as follows:

[Airflow Connection Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDLa7.png)

I have tried:

- `airflow connections get` command within the container does return the connection config.
- the `pg_isready` command from within airflow container (in bash), as well as various psql commands, do not work. When outside the container, on the host machine, they work.
- I tried using ping from within the airflow container, but as docker installs are minimal it does not seem to have ping installed. Is there any other way to test this?

What I would like to ultimately do:

I have been tasked with creating a dag that creates a backup of the entire postgres server. I would like to use pg_dump using BashOperator. I cannot do this without airflow being able to connect to the postgresql server.

Comment: Why would airflow interface need to connect to postgres through a connection if you are using pg_dump on the shell through bashoperator? I'm not Airflow expert but that doesn't feel right. I DO agree that you should be able to connect with an airflow connection and that your inability to do so suggests you will have issues down in a bash shell as well. Also, unrelated, is that the right port for you postgres database? I only ask because I don't believe it's default.

Comment: Those are all good questions. The pg_dump command requires passing parameters like host, port, etc, and that did not work. That is when I went down the path of airflow not being able to see the server at all. 

The port is correct, I can connect to it using various other methods (pgadmin, bash when not in container, etc), it is definitely not default. I did not set it up so I do not know why they chose this port.

Comment: It sounds like a networking issue. Are you able to telnet or netcat to that port on your airflow system's shell? Perhaps this is more of a docker or k8s issue?

Comment: This is my current thought as well, after sleeping on it. I will test and report back/edit.

I think it might be the way docker networking is configured for this container. I will investigate the differences. Thank you.